# Pandas selecting duplicates that occur n times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe how would I select duplicates that occur two times only

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Two','Twice','Twice','three','three','three','one', 'Two'],
'key':[2,2,2,1,1,3,1,1,],
'Last':['Foo','Macy','Gayson','Simpson','Diablo','Niggah','Simpson', 'Mortimer']
})


r=df[df.duplicated(subset=['Name'], keep =False)]


print(r)
```

so I would get:

```
       Last   Name  key
0       Foo    Two    2
1      Macy  Twice    2
2    Gayson  Twice    2
7  Mortimer    Two    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
In [80]: df.groupby('Name').filter(lambda x: len(x) == 2)
Out[80]:
       Last   Name  key
0       Foo    Two    2
1      Macy  Twice    2
2    Gayson  Twice    2
7  Mortimer    Two    1
```